# Installing xetex-pstricks on TeXLive

Tags: xetex, pstricks, windows, texworks

I installed xetex-pstricks via

```
tlmgr install xetex-pstricks
tlmgr update xetex-pstricks
```

on my Windows 7 machine with a TeXLive installation.

```
tlmgr info xetex-pstricks --list
```

gave me info on these files:

```
texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
texmf-dist/tex/xetex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
```

Now, when I want to use `xetex-pstricks`, the xelatex underlying TeXWorks complains on a missing

```
 xetex-pstricks.sty
```

How can I install this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such file.

If you have a `\usepackage{xetex-pstricks}` line in your preamble, remove it. The package simply consists in configuration files, `pstricks.con` (one for `xetex` and one for `xelatex`) to be used by `xdvipdfmx`. They are automatically read on compiling with xetex/xelatex, but not with other compilers.